# Cannot run WSL on Acer 5 2022

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have tried to run the windows linux subsystem on Acer Aspire 5 5 2022 but it tells me:

```
WslRegistrerDistribution failed with error:0x80370102
Please enable Virtual Machine Platform  Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
```

I went to the bios and I have enabled as described in [this](https://community.acer.com/en/kb/articles/14750-how-to-enable-virtualization-technology-on-acer-products) article but still the error persists.

[image]

Anyone can give any hints?

In [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting) guide they say again to enable virtualization but I guess my PC simply does not support the type of virtualization that Windows wants.

Comment: What optional Windows features do you have enabled. [Exit] your question and include a screenshot. What version of Windows 11 are you running?

Comment: @John - The author’s screenshot clear shows they have hardware virtualization enabled.

Comment: @Ramhound  Windows 11 Home, version 22H2

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the necessary information required to answer your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Comment: If you cannot get WSL working, consider running Linux in a virtual machine such as VirtualBox (https://www.virtualbox.org/) or an alternative (https://alternativeto.net/software/virtualbox/). There are various distros of Linux preconfigured for VirtualBox (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

Answer (score 0):

> but I guess my PC simply does not support the type of virtualization that Windows wants."

It seems that it does, and you do have it enabled.  The most *likely* (and hopefully correct, since it is the easiest) solution is that you still need to enable the "Virtual Machine Platform" (VMP) feature in Windows.

This would normally have been done during the `wsl --install`, but probably didn't complete because, when you ran it the first time, you didn't yet have the BIOS features enabled.  So you'll probably (again, hopefully) need to turn that on manually at this point.

To do so:

- Search for *Turn Windows features on or off* in the Start menu.
- Enable the *Virtual Machine Platform*
- Reboot
- Open PowerShell (as a regular user, *not* Administrator)
- `wsl -l -v`
- If there's an existing "Ubuntu" (or other, non-Docker) distribution there:

  - Try `wsl ~` to start it.
- If there's not an existing distribution:

  - `ubuntu.exe`, which should install and register the distribution (assuming you previously did a `wsl --install`)
- If that command doesn't work, go to the Microsoft Store, search for and install a WSL distribution.  "Ubuntu" (without a version) is the most common and should install 22.04 at this point.

Given the aborted installation, it's tough to say *exactly* what you'll need to do to recover after enabling the VMP, but hopefully the above will work.